# How do I use http-authentification with Liferay?

Tags: liferay, http-authentication, liferay-6

How do I get users to authenticate by http-auth before they can access Liferay?

More specific: How do I use http-auth instead of Liferay's sign-in page or portlets. Access to Liferay should be completely blocked unless credentials have been presented by http-auth.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak directly to how Liferay works, however, in JBoss Portal you have to manually modify the Portal's web.xml to include the appropriate authentication mechanism and desired roles.

I would assume that Liferay would probably be the same course of action since they are both Java-based web applications at their cores.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not near my (liferay)  computer at the moment but you can configure Liferay by placing a portal-ext.properties in the bundle directory,  and there are several authentication modules available simply by specifying an alternate class.